# TensorFlow - exporting object detection model for iOS

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I have trained an object detection model using the object detection API and need to export it to run on iOS.
I have created a .pb file using the export_inference_graph.py, but unfortunately this file generated a loading error when used within an iOS app (https://github.com/KleinYuan/tensorflow-yolo-ios).
I have read that there are additional steps to freeze and then simplify the model, but I haven't found a step-by-step solution to do that. Any suggestion?

Error:
yolo-ios/tensorflow_utils.mm:169] Could not create TensorFlow Graph: Invalid argument: No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'Equal' with these attrs.  Registered devices: [CPU], Registered kernels:
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_FLOAT]

```
 [[Node: Postprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppression/MultiClassNonMaxSuppression/Equal = Equal[T=DT_INT32](Postprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppression/MultiClassNonMaxSuppression/strided_slice, Postprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppression/MultiClassNonMaxSuppression/strided_slice_1)]]
```

ps: notice that the trained model loads and runs fine on PC if I use it in the ipython notebook https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb

Comment: Can you say what kinds of errors you get?

Comment: Thanks Jonathan! I reported the error. However, I am interested in the right steps to do that within iOS, regardless of the actual app I am using.